# How do you cancel all open trades for a Stellar account?

Tags: transactions, java-sdk, manageofferoperation

I'm looking at the Java docs and I can't find any way to delete every order for an account. Is there an easy way to cancel/remove all open trades/offers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't method for bulk cancelling.

Stellar cancels offers by setting the Amount parameter to 0. [From the site](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#manage-offer)

> Manage Offer: Parameters [...] Amount: Amount of selling being sold. Set to 0 if you want to delete an existing offer.

So, you could loop through your open orders and update the amount to 0 (cancelling them). The code below assumes that you're trading XLM for an `asset` and have an Account loaded.

```
KeyPair pair = account.getKeyPair();
Page<OfferResponse> openOffers = server.offers().forAccount(pair).limit(100).execute();

//Get number of open bids
int numBids = openOffers.getRecords().size();

for (int x = 0; numBids > x; x++){
  long offerID = openOffers.getRecords().get(x).getId();
  ManageOfferOperation deleteOffer = new ManageOfferOperation.Builder(new AssetTypeNative(), asset, "0", "1").setSourceAccount(pair).setOfferId(offerID).build();

  Transaction transaction = new Transaction.Builder(account.getAccountResponse()).addOperation(deleteOffer).build();
  SubmitTransactionResponse response = server.submitTransaction(transaction);

  transaction.sign(pair);
}
```

I tested this and its a bit slow, but works (could always multithread).

Comment: You can add up to 100 operations to a single transaction so it should speed this up.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no method for canceling all your offers in one go, you need to submit many `manageOfferOp` together, one for each offer. The good news is that you can submit up to 100 of this operations in one transaction.

I included a script that does exactly this, first it retrieves the first page of offers you have open and creates a transaction to cancel all of them, then moves on the next page to cancel them and so on.

```
var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk')
StellarSdk.Network.useTestNetwork();
let server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org')


function parseAsset(asset) {
  if (asset.asset_type == 'native') {
    return StellarSdk.Asset.native();
  } else {
    return new StellarSdk.Asset(asset.asset_code, asset.asset_issuer);
  }
}


function cancelOffers(kp, account, res) {
  let offers = res.records;
  if (offers.length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  let operations = offers.map(offer => {
    // map offer to offer operation
    let buying = parseAsset(offer.buying);
    let selling = parseAsset(offer.selling);
    return StellarSdk.Operation.manageOffer({
      buying: buying,
      selling: selling,
      amount: '0',
      price: offer.price_r,
      offerId: offer.id,
    });
  });

  let builder = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account);
  builder.operations = operations;
  let tx = builder.build();
  tx.sign(kp);

  server.submitTransaction(tx).then(tx_res => {
    console.log(tx_res);
  }).then(() => {
    // if you have more than 100 offers, you need to retrieve
    // the next page.
    res.next().then(account, offers => cancelOffers(kp, account, offers));
  });
}

// Create transaction with first signer
let kp = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret('SAD6NO7EOFZX25B2TJIHQM3JXNRFRAHEDRREV5NXDZC5PN23AHXLFBCZ')

server.loadAccount(kp.publicKey()).then(account => {
  server.offers('accounts', kp.publicKey()).call().then(offers => {
    return cancelOffers(kp, account, offers);
  });
});
```